# How display my errors default for Stripe?

Tags: vue.js, stripe-payments

I use this [vue-stripe-checkout](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-stripe-checkout) (Vue.js), all works fine but if i write a fake number of card a automatic message is display and say "you'r number is incorrect".

Is what i want but i don't know how to add style on that, because is as 0 style and is very ugly.
The style object don't work on that, i found in documentation a Slots for "card-errors" but i don't know what means.

If someone can help me ?

```
<stripe-elements
            :styleObject="style"
            ref="elementsRef"
            :pk="publishableKey"
            locale="fr"
            @token="tokenCreated"
            @loading="loading = $event"
        >
        </stripe-elements>
        <button class="btn btn-success px-5" @click="submit">Payer</button>
```

Comment: Yes, it sounds you would style the `card-errors` element on the page! Unfortunately I have zero experience with Vue or what a Slot is so I'm not sure how you'd approach that, maybe someone else can chime in or there is information online or you can ask the maintainers of that plugin on Github.

Comment: Thanks for you'r reply, unfortunately i search and don't found a response because the plugin is not most popular. Maybe someone got answer or understand the functionnality = /

Thanks !